# Can I use code with MIT license with my GPLv2 or v3 code?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, gpl-3, gpl-2

Let's say that I make a program and I put it on Github with GPLv2 license. Can i later add code from another person that has MIT license (adding his/her license in the repository of course).

How about GPLv3?

Comment: @apsillers thanks! should I delete the question?

Comment: @Ricardo No. If it is duplicate it can be marked as duplicate so other people can find the answer too.

Comment: To reiterate what Brandin said, Stack Exchange tries hard to eliminate answer fragmentation. There's nothing wrong with this question; we just want to avoid someone answering it and creating two answers to the same problem in different question-threads. Properly-closed duplicate questions can even be advantageous, since a spread of different question-variants can catch different search terms in search engines and all direct to the same master canonical answer.